# ListPreference coding value not executing inside if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, listpreference, arrays, getstring

Can you check my code for anything missing?

I'm trying to get use the value from a listpreference in an if statement but the if statement never responds to the value stored in the listpreference.

Here the coding I'm using:

```
    String stringChimeVolume = clockSettings.getString("ChimeVolume",
            "Default");


    Toast.makeText(context, "The preference is: " + stringChimeVolume,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (stringChimeVolume == "2") {
        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                2, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);

        Toast.makeText(context, "The volume is at 2: ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (stringChimeVolume == "3") {
        Toast.makeText(context, "The volume is at 3: ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                7, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
    }

    else if (stringChimeVolume == "4") {
        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                15, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
    }
```

I used the first Toast statement to ensure a value was there. It has the value of 2 but the Toast in the if statement for "2" is not executing.

Here is the arrays.xml I used for the listpreference:

```
<string-array name="chimeVolumeLabels">
    <item>Use System Volume</item>
    <item>Emad</item>
    <item>Medium</item>
    <item>Loud</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="chimeVolumeValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

This is the settings.xml with the listpreference:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Media:">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="ChimeWhenMusicIsPlaying"
        android:title="@string/ChimeWhenMusicIsPlayingTitle" android:summary="@string/ChimeWhenMusicIsPlayingSummary"
        android:defaultValue="false" />

    <ListPreference android:title="Chime Volume"
        android:key="ChimeVolume" android:summary="Select volume for the chiming sound."
        android:entries="@array/chimeVolumeLabels" android:entryValues="@array/chimeVolumeValues"
        android:defaultValue="1" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .equals instead of ==  since == compare references not the actual value

like

```
if (stringChimeVolume.equals( "2")) instead of 


if (stringChimeVolume== "2")
```

Comment: Hi Nammari, Thanks for the help. Your code works like a dream. :-) Truly, Emad